# Fill parent in active mode bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am very new to web.
can some one please help me with this easy and stupidy questions.

I made this navigation bar in bootstrap.

Here is the link to what i made.

[www.headsuppoker.tk](http://headsuppoker.tk/)

in the navigation bar the active item "Home" is not fully highlited to fill the total height of navigation bar with dark black.
plz tell me how to do this.

thanks in advance.

Comment: can you make a fiddle with the relevant code please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest adding this Code to your CSS as it will also center your Navigation-Items:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a {
    padding: 18px 15px !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude. Cloud you please tell me how to center the inactive item too.

Comment: Happy to help. For centering non-active items, replace the `.active` with `li` in the code.

Answer (score 0):

On line 7 of the `bootstrap.min.css`, under `.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a`, add `padding-bottom: 25px !important` to extend the black all the way down. Looks like line 4415 when it's expanded.

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus{
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#080808
    padding-bottom:25px !important;/* <----Add This Line*/
}
```